# PIL: changing color isn't corrent if the image is resized before

Tags: image, python-3.x, colors, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to be able to recolor images after I have resized them, because if I do so before it takes too long since the originals are too big.
Codes:
fast, but bad:

```
img = Image.open("piimage.png")        
img = img.resize((30,30), Image.ANTIALIAS)
pixdata = img.load()
for y in range(img.size[1]):
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        if pixdata[x, y] == (255, 255, 255, 255):
            pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
self.piimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

slow, but good:

```
img = Image.open("piimage.png")
pixdata = img.load()
for y in range(img.size[1]):
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        if pixdata[x, y] == (255, 255, 255, 255):
            pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 255)        
img = img.resize((30,30), Image.ANTIALIAS)
self.piimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

I' ve found this code here on stackoverflow, but that sample didn't have resize, but I need it since I use them for small buttons. The only difference between the upper and the lower is the position of the resize command.
Why does this happen and how to work around it ?
Image showing results:
[image]

Comment: The white pixels are being interpolated into the surrounding red background when you resize it. You would have the same problem in a paint program.

Answer (score 0):

The white pixels are not precisely white anymore after resizing with ANTIALIAS. Therefore, your `if` statement should not be too strict anymore. Better is to change it to something like this:

```
white_threshold = 208
if pixdata[x, y][0] <= white_threshold and
   pixdata[x, y][1] <= white_threshold and
   pixdata[x, y][2] <= white_threshold:
    pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
```

You then might want to play around with the threshold value.

Sidenote: I am pretty sure there are faster ways than a double for loop to loop over all the pixels, although I don't recall them from the top of my head.

Comment: Isn't there a possibilty to check wehter the pixel isn't empty ? Something like if pixdata[x, y] not = some statement I'd like to know: do the recoloring, because in my program it wouldn't be always white, and these images are on buttons so the empty space needs to stay empty.

Comment: How do you define "empty"?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a satisfactory solution:

```
def makeimage(self):
    img = Image.open("piimagefunny.png")        
    img = img.resize((100,100))
    pixdata = img.load()
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        for x in range(img.size[0]):
            if pixdata[x, y] <= (255, 255, 255, 255) and pixdata[x, y] > (0, 0, 0, 10):                
                pixdata[x, y] = (128, 128, 128)
    img = img.resize((30,30), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.piimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

The difference is to resize it before, no need for ANTIALIAS, but bigger than what you want, so that later the ANTIALIAS has some pixels to work with, also the above example recolors any color of the image.

Comment: Be careful when comparing tuples with a `<`: it only compares the first element in the tuple! Try out in the console `(10,0) < (5,5)` and `(0,10) < (5,5)` to convince yourself that this is dangerous.